# Pattern to many parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns

I'm creating an application that has a single Entrypoint, the application user has 10 parameters to fill, only 3 are optional. These parameters are filled in an object called ContextConfig. When the application starts there 10 parameters are delivered for 3 objects and different objects takes repetitive parameters, are there any pattern to this?

```
class DeltaContext:
    def __init__(self, delta_context: DeltaContextConfig):

        self.delta_context = delta_context

        self.hive_operations = HiveOperations(
            hive_config=HiveConfig(
                spark_df=self.delta_context.spark_df,
                table_name=self.delta_context.table_name,
                database_name=self.delta_context.database_name,
                partition_column=self.delta_context.partition_column,
                destination_path=self.delta_context.destination_path,
                spark_context=self.delta_context.spark_context,
            )
        )
        self.delta_writer = DeltaWriter(
            delta_write_config=DeltaWriteConfig(
                spark_df=self.delta_context.spark_df,
                column_to_order=self.delta_context.column_to_order,
                destination_path=self.delta_context.destination_path,
                partition_column=self.delta_context.partition_column,
                primary_key=self.delta_context.primary_key,
                files_count_first_batch=self.delta_context.files_count_first_batch,
                spark_context=delta_context.spark_context,
                operation_type=delta_context.operation_type,
                update_condition=delta_context.update_condition,
                set_expression=delta_context.set_expression
            )
        )
        self.auto_compaction = AutoCompaction(
            auto_compaction_config=AutoCompactionConfig(
                spark_context=self.delta_context.spark_context,
                destination_path=self.delta_context.destination_path,
                partition_column=self.delta_context.partition_column,
                ideal_file_size=self.delta_context.ideal_file_size,
                compaction_interval_time=self.delta_context.compaction_interval_time,
            )
        )
```

How can I make it better?

Comment: Make the other constructors accept a `DeltaContextConfig` and extract the parts relevant to them.

Comment: But it is a good pattern pass parameter that won't be used?

Comment: You will only pass one parameter, that has many attributes. When you write a method, do you worry about all the attributes of the class it isn't using?

Comment: I feel like something like `**kwargs` might be useful here in all of the classes (and initial input). This way the set of entries is the same for everything but you only use what is relevant

Comment: Could be better create for example, an AutoCompaction factory that receives DeltaContextConfig and Give Back an AutoCompaction?